# WSO2 Duo Connector @carbon.super

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We are currently using WSO2IS in combination with Duo Security for 2FA on some of our sites.  We upgraded from 5.3.4 to 5.7.4 and now our Duo Connector is appending @carbon.super to the username when we hit any site that we have configured to use Duo.

How do I stop it from doing this?  We are currently running WSO2 5.7.4, and trying to use the Duo 1.0.11 Connector and the associated duoauthentication.war file.

the Duo IDP looks right.  I have tried various values such as 1, and true, and TRUE for the disable tenant domain, but it doesn't appear to do anything -- even after restarting WSO2 after each change.

Any ideas what I am missing?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsbAj.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/bK7v2.png  (this is a screen shot of the disable tenant domain settings).

Edit: Following along with the suggestion of Nipun, I'm adding a screenshot of the Advanced Settings for my SP which is under Local & Outbound Authentication Config.

[Advanced Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsbAj.png)

per Nipun's suggestion below, I enabled

true

in repository/conf/carbon.xml

and also in the repository/conf/identity/application-authentication.xml, I set up the following under AuthenticatorsConfig.

```
             <AuthenticatorConfig name="DuoAuthenticator" enabled="true">
                  <Parameter name="usecase">association</Parameter>
                  <Parameter name="sendDuoToFederatedMobileAttribute">true</Parameter>
                  <Parameter name="federatedMobileNumberAttributeKey">http://wso2.org/claims/mobile</Parameter>
                  <Parameter name="secondaryUserstore">primary</Parameter>
             </AuthenticatorConfig>
```

Further edits:

I notice in my repository/logs/audit.log file that I'm seeing lines like this:

```
[2020-05-12 16:41:44,120]  INFO {AUDIT_LOG}-  Initiator : my.user@myemail.net | Action : LoginStepSuccess | Target : ApplicationAuthenticationFramework | Data : { "ContextIdentifier" : "269e9fa9-242f-4ee1-b9ac-01355347e087","AuthenticatedUser" : "my.user@myemail.net","AuthenticatedUserTenantDomain" : "carbon.super","ServiceProviderName" : "castest","RequestType" : "cas","RelyingParty" : "castest","AuthenticatedIdP" : "LOCAL" } | Result : Success
```

It still lists the AuthenticatingUserTenantDomain as carbon.super -- shoudln't that be myemail.net or something? -- My system is connected to ActiveDirectory via Read Only LDAP.

This is what I'm seeing in the Duo Security Reports:

[duosecurity-access-denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSOrL.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your Service Provider's `Local & Outbound Authentication Configuration` section **uncheck** the `Use tenant domain in local subject identifier` option.
[image]

Comment: Nipun,  Thanks for the quick response.  That checkbox is already unchecked on this SP.  The only difference is that in our screen, we are using Duo as the second step in the authentication process, so we have the "Advanced" option selected.  I've attached a screenshot of the Advanced screen to the OP.

Comment: Image 2 is what my advance configuration screen looks like.

Comment: Did you provide an email address in the 'identifier-first' step? (Or was it just a username without the `@` sign?) Also, have you enabled this property in the `carbon.xml` file? `<EnableEmailUserName>true</EnableEmailUserName>`. If you are using an email address to login, you should enable this property. (Needs a restart)

Comment: Nipun,  I just went back and added the EnableEmailuserName line to the carbon.xml file.  We are only using "basic" in our advanced section in step 1, not the identifier first.  It is still not working.

Comment: I should also add that we are using Oracle Java, and not OpenJDK.

Comment: I'm posting this here for others who are having a similar issue.  We are using WSO2 IS 5.7.4, and to get it working correctly I had to use the Duo Connector v1.0.3.

org.wso2.carbon.extension.identity.authenticator.duo.connector-1.0.3.jar is the one that is working correctly for us.